# Is it bad practice to declare instance variable values based on the name of the class?

Tags: ruby, oop

Let's say I have a couple subclasses that inherit from a base class like this:

```
class Base

  def initialize
    @name = self.class.name
    @num1 = 10;
    @num2 = 5;
  end

  def speak
    puts "My name is #{name}"
  end

end

class Sub1 < Base
end

class Sub2 < Base
end

class Sub3 < Base
end
```

Is it bad practice to declare the instance variable of `@name` to the name of the class? Would it be better to do something like this?

```
class Base

  def initialize
    @feet = 10;
    @inches = 5;
  end

  def speak
    puts "My name is #{name}"
  end

end

class Sub1 < Base
  def initialize
    super()
    @name = "Sub1"
  end
end

class Sub2 < Base
  def initialize
    super()
    @name = "Sub2"
  end
end

class Sub3 < Base
  def initialize
    super()
    @name = "Sub3"
  end
end
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why even assign the class name to an ivar at all? It's already known; I'd just define a `name` accessor which returns `self.class.name`.

Comment: Why do you need `@name` when you can just use `self.class.name` or `myObject.class.name` from the outside?

Comment: Note that if you replace the antepenultimate line of `Sub1` with `@name = self.class.to_s` then `Sub1.new.instance_variable_get(:@name)
 #=> "Sub1"`. (You could instead write `... instance_variable_get('@name')`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `@name` is always intended to be equal to the class name, you don't need it – just use `self.class.name` or `myObject.class.name` directly, or define an accessor method which returns it if you don't want to use `.class.name` from the outside. Initializing it manually would be bad practice since you'd always have to remember to do it in every subclass and changes to subclass names would need to be replicated to the initialization.

If `@name` is *not* always going to equal the class name in every subclass, then personally I'd still provide a default implementation where it is initialized from `self.class.name` and let subclasses override it as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is more concise. What you probably should be doing is evaluating this in a lazy capacity:

```
def name
  @name ||= self.class.to_s.split(/::/).last
end
```

That way you don't need to worry about assignment and any subclass can initialize if necessary with an override. Your `speak` method will continue to work without modification as presumably you had declared `attr_reader :name` for that to work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite pointless, look at this output:

```
class Base
   def name
     self.class.name
   end
end

class Sub1 < Base
  # This declaration is useless
  def name
    self.class.name
  end
end

class Sub2 < Base
end

b = Base.new
b.name # "Base"

c = Sub1.new
c.name # "Sub1"

d = Sub2.new
d.name # "Sub2" (this function is inherited from base, but is called from Sub2 class context)
```

Next thing in ruby, you can use **superclass** method to get parent class name

```
 Sub2.superclass.name # "Base"
```